# Inheritance/Interface design of a game

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, architecture

I'm designing a game, but I can't quite get my head around the inheritance structure. I'm normally fairly good at it, but this one just has too much overlap and I can't decide on it all.

I'm seeking to model sailing vessels - think the Age of Sail. Presumably therefore everything extends a Vessel class.

There are then several types of vessel style: rowed (galleys, canoes), square-rig, fore-and-aft rig, with different behaviour. Each of these is further subdivided into several other types. I can't decide whether this should be a series of interfaces or extensions of Vessel. Note also that there can be some cross over (a vessel can be both rowed and square rigged) which leads me to think interfaces?

Ships also have different behaviours: merchant vessels, men of war, privateer, pirates. I really can't work out whether this should be an interface or an extension of another class. There is no crossover of type in this case, however.

Finally there are several behaviours which individual ships can have. Merchants may be in a convoy (defend themselves) or independent (run away). Men of war almost always attack unless heavily outgunned... but may work in fleets, squadrons or independently. Privateers and pirates only attack if weaker - usually independently but occasionally in pairs. I'm assuming that this should be an interface too?

My big problem is that each style of ship (frigate, battleship etc) can fulfil almost any of these roles, so I can't build a simple solid inheritance structure. Frigate can't extend man-o-war because some are privateers. Sloop can't extend square rigged because some are fore and aft rigged. etcetc.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, I'm at a bit of a loose end.
Thanks

Comment: The two ideas which come to mind off the top of my head are "component-based design" and "strategy pattern". As far as the different behaviours that individual ships can have, that's definitely saying strategy pattern to me - each ship is using one of a variety of different strategies. See here on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

Comment: A ship may go from merchant vessel to pirate **at run time**, so interfaces won't work for this kind of dynamic behaviour.

Comment: @amadeus: did not get your point. If you are "programming for interfaces", you can precisely do that.

Comment: @amadeus - ships will not dynamically change from being a merchant to a pirate, it's more that each style of vessel can be one or the other when created.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys - I still can't get the most fundamental problem though. How do I create (at runtime) vessels of each combination without needing a subclass for each combination? I'm likely to end up with SquareRiggedPirateSloop, SquareRiggedPirateFrigate, ForeAndAftPirateSloop, ForeAndAftMerchantSloop etc.

Comment: @Jon: As an example, you could do `Ship frigate = new Ship(); frigate.AddPropulsionMechanism(new SailPropulsionMechanism()); frigate.SetStrategy(new ManOfWarStrategy());`.

Comment: If it were me, I'd switch to a data-driven approach and have blueprints for each particular type of ship, specifying what propulsion mechanisms they have and what strategy they use. Then you could just say e.g. `Ship frigate = Ship.CreateFromBlueprint("Frigate");`.

Comment: Ah, superb - thanks - I'm getting it now :)

Comment: this is interesting. please publish your design when you decide on one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here are some ideas:

- Vessels have one or more means of propulsion (oars, sails, etc.), which you can model by composition (e.g. have a list of propulsion methods).
- Vessels use one of a variety of strategies (use the strategy pattern -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern -- for this)
- Strategies which depend on the presence of other nearby ships will need some way of querying for those other ships -- so you'll need some sort of data structure that allows you to find which objects are near which other objects (look into the sort of data structures that are used for broad-phase collision detection)

As an alternative to the strategy pattern, you could switch to using a component-based design. In this setup, a vessel would be composed of one or more propulsion components, a strategy component, etc. You could then combine individual components as you see fit to make different vessels.

As an extra bonus, component-based designs are very helpful if you want your game to be data-driven, because you can just write a saver/loader for each different type of component, rather than for each possible type of vessel.

You might want to see here if you're interested in this sort of approach:

http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/

Answer (score 5):

Make the "behavior" part as interfaces. That will help you assigning different behaviors to different ships without problem. [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is helpful here. In a nutshell, it states that the changeable and the constant properties should be separated.

For different means of movements, composition sounds like the most suitable answer at this moment.

Regarding the "but may work in fleets, squadrons or independently. Privateers and pirates only attack if weaker - usually independently but occasionally in pairs." part, I guess this has nothing to do with the inheritance tree. You can make "groups" of classes depending up on your need.

This might help you:

[image]

"There are then several types of vessel style:..." is specifying different possible behaviors. So "Movable" interface and its subclasses are for that. In the "Vessel" class, you can have a member of type "Movable". Since "Movable" is an interface, any class which implements it, is assignable to this member. So any subclass of Vessel can have any possible behavior, which we cna change at runtime as well. You can also make it an ArrayList. (Not sure if you actually want to do it or not). But if you need multiple different behaviors for a same vessel, you can do it.

When you say "Ships also have different behaviours:..." it feels like separate classes extending Vessel will satisfy this requirement. The sentence "There is no crossover of type in this case, however." makes life easier.

For the nest para "Finally there are several behaviours which individual ships can have...", you should add one more member for different possible behaviors. It will mostly be an ArrayList as one vessel will have multiple attack modes.

Fro the last para, if you can give some more details, I may be able to give some more ideas.

Comment: That diagram is the sort of idea I originally came up with - however I realised that I still need another layer. For example, how do I create three vessels. A square-rigged merchant sloop, another fore and aft rigged and a fore and aft rigged pirate sloop? I'd need a LOT more classes to get all the possible combinations in. I'd end up with FAPirateSloop extends Pirate implements ForeAndAft, SQPirateSloop extends Pirate implements SquareRigged etcetc.

Answer (score 2):

I want to provide a bit of advice based on the second paragraph of Bhusan's answer, which I quote here in full:

"Regarding the "but may work in fleets, squadrons or independently. Privateers and pirates only attack if weaker - usually independently but occasionally in pairs." part, I guess this has nothing to do with the inheritance tree. You can make "groups" of classes depending up on your need."

This leads me to believe that you additionally may want to consider the Composite pattern for *certain* groups of ships, at least those that are comprised of ships that all share the same behavior.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern where it is written that "the composite pattern describes that a group of objects are to be treated in the same way as a single instance of an object."

For instance you say "Merchants may be in a convoy (defend themselves)", but presumably they can defend themselves individually as well?  This is all easier said than done of course, and my advice to you is to not over-think it and start with a very small subset of what you want to do as a protoype

Comment: Composite will work for groups that always stick together, but will need careful handling when ships can break away from the main group -- e.g. they might need to be considered to leave the composite if they sail too far away.

Comment: I don't believe composite patterns takes a position on static or dynamic groups in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the types and use the [strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) pattern. 
 
Immutable properties should be bound to the inheritance tree (e.g. a frigate won't turn into canoe, these are exact, non-behavioral types, inheriting from vessel) and everything that may change should be stored as references to behavioral types which are intrachangable. (Man-o-war is a behavioral type) 
AI should be handled separately, for instance with states, but that is also have to be in a different module in your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thinking about it as strictly inheritance, I think you need to think about object [Composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) and how that can help make things easier.

For example: a Ship **has a** Behaviour. (Composition... the ship delegates to the behaviour to determine how to react to X situation)

A Pirate **is a** Behaviour (Inheritance from a Behaviour interface)...

Comment: Technically speaking, a pirate is an angry fellow with an eye patch who says "Arrr!" a lot and makes people walk the plank. Pirate-like behaviour is a behaviour :) Note that this isn't an entirely facetious point, in that people seeing a class called `Pirate` wouldn't expect it to be a behaviour.

Comment: @StuartGolodetz - that could perhaps be where I use "Piracy" as a class instead, to remove confusion?

Comment: Good point on being careful about naming... I'll admit I just pulled from the original question without thinking too much about it and who doesn't like pirates? (Well... besides ninjas) :D

Comment: Pirate is not a behavior -> behavior is not an object in our system. Ship has a lot of Pirates and pirate make some behavior dependent on type of pirate. So you have IPirate and CaptainPirate which implements the interface. In your interface you have declaration of reaction to something with visitor pattern.

Comment: @AlexTheo: +1 for introducing a `CaptainPirate` class. It sounds like you're arguing for the behaviour of the ship to partly depend on the composition of its crew, which sounds interesting. Might be an overcomplicated model here though, not sure.

Comment: This is a real world representation using OOA/OOD ;)

Comment: @StuartGolodetz - in that situation I'd probably split it into different PirateCaptain, PirateOfficer, PirateCrew etc. For the scope of this game, however, "Crew" is an asset (rather like ammunition) rather than a complex object. Pirate (object) and Piracy (behaviour) are as in depth as I'm likely to need. I could maybe call Pirate Corsair to ease confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You should not extend the Vessel class.  Rather, a Vessel object should contain other objects that describe it.  (This is known as Dependency Injection, to be annoyingly pedantic--forget I said that.)  You have a Propulsion class, with instances for square-sails, fore-and-aft, and oars.  You might want special instances of each for big and small hulls.  You have a Behavior class to handle their attitude.  Sometimes a simple integer works as well as a class.  Your Armament class could be, instead, just a number of guns.  (Or two numbers, one for poundage.)  If you expect to ram, or have a ship loaded with rockets, or need to distinguish between long guns and carronades, you might need to go back to using the a class.

This lets you switch characteristics on the fly if you want--though you probably don't.  Still, you can go from sail to using sweeps, or switch bold ship-of-the-line behavior with save-the-cargo behavior of a merchant to implement a captain losing his nerve.  Anyway, it's there if you need it.

Comment: A good concise reply, thanks - I'd pretty much gleaned the same idea together from a combination of other answers, but you phrase it well.